# cordova-plugin-fcm and ionic platform add ios causes error code 65

Tags: android, ios, firebase, ionic-framework, cordova-plugin-fcm

I'm creating an android/ios application using ionic 1.

A list of the version.

```
cordova: 7.0.1
ionic: 2.2.2
ios-deploy: 1.9.1 
ios-sim: 6.0.0
node: v8.3.0
```

A list of the plugins I used.

```
cordova-plugin-compat 1.1.0 "Compat"
cordova-plugin-console 1.0.7 "Console"
cordova-plugin-device 1.1.6 "Device"
cordova-plugin-facebook4 1.7.4 "Facebook Connect"
cordova-plugin-file 4.3.3 "File"
cordova-plugin-file-transfer 1.6.3 "File Transfer"
cordova-plugin-firebase 0.1.24 "Google Firebase Plugin"
cordova-plugin-geolocation 2.4.3 "Geolocation"
cordova-plugin-ignore-lint-translation 0.0.1 "cordova-plugin-ignore-lint-translation"
cordova-plugin-image-picker 1.1.1 "ImagePicker"
cordova-plugin-inappbrowser 1.7.1 "InAppBrowser"
cordova-plugin-splashscreen 4.0.3 "Splashscreen"
cordova-plugin-statusbar 2.2.3 "StatusBar"
cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.3.2 "Whitelist"
cordova.plugins.diagnostic 3.5.0 "Diagnostic"
ionic-plugin-keyboard 2.2.1 "Keyboard"
phonegap-plugin-push 1.10.5 "PushPlugin"
```

I implemented the push notification using fcm and the android push was successful using phonegap-plugin-push.

However ios push does not work by phonegap-plugin-push, So I installed an additional plugin. but fails when `ionic run`.

(Note that before installing additional plugins, both android/ios were successful in the ionic run.)

If I install cordova-plugin-fcm and run `ionic platform add ios` command, the following error occurs.

```
duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_GtalkSelectiveAck in:
    /Users/pbh/project/frontend/luxlab_front/platforms/ios/Pods/GoogleCloudMessaging/Libraries/libGcmLib.a(GtalkExtensions.pb.o)
    럭스랩/Plugins/cordova-plugin-fcm/FirebaseMessaging.framework/FirebaseMessaging(GtalkExtensions.pb_3df3b2963f0a00a0a06e6bc7758c4642.o)
ld: 33 duplicate symbols for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)


** ARCHIVE FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
    Ld /Users/pbh/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/럭스랩-frtekduffawmjpcdcfcknnsswolo/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/럭스랩/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/럭스랩.build/Debug-iphoneos/럭스랩.build/Objects-normal/arm64/럭스랩 normal arm64
(1 failure)

Error: Error code 65 for command: xcodebuild with args: -xcconfig,/Users/pbh/project/frontend/luxlab_front/platforms/ios/cordova/build-debug.xcconfig,-workspace,럭스랩.xcworkspace,-scheme,럭스랩,-configuration,Debug,-destination,generic/platform=iOS,-archivePath,럭스랩.xcarchive,archive,CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR=/Users/pbh/project/frontend/luxlab_front/platforms/ios/build/device,SHARED_PRECOMPS_DIR=/Users/pbh/project/frontend/luxlab_front/platforms/ios/build/sharedpch
```

And if I run `ionic run android`, I will get an error like below.

```
:processDebugGoogleServices

Found com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:11+, but version 9.0.0 is needed for the google-services plugin.

:processDebugGoogleServices FAILED




FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:

Execution failed for task ':processDebugGoogleServices'.

> 
Please fix the version conflict either by updating the version of the google-services plugin (information about the latest version is available at https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.google.gms.google-services/) or updating the version of com.google.android.gms to 9.0.0.

* Try:
Run with 
--stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.



BUILD FAILED


Total time: 2.34 secs

Error: /Users/pbh/project/frontend/luxlab_front/platforms/android/gradlew: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':processDebugGoogleServices'.
> Please fix the version conflict either by updating the version of the google-services plugin (information about the latest version is available at https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.google.gms.google-services/) or updating the version of com.google.android.gms to 9.0.0.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
```

I tried again with cordova-plugin-firebase plugin.
But it also fails when building the application.

`ionic run android`

```
/Users/pbh/project/frontend/luxlab_front/platforms/android/res/values/strings.xml: Error: Found item String/google_app_id more than one time

:mergeDebugResources 
FAILED


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.


* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':mergeDebugResources'.

> /Users/pbh/project/frontend/luxlab_front/platforms/android/res/values/strings.xml: Error: Found item String/google_app_id more than one time

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace
 option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.



BUILD FAILED

Total time: 11.454 secs

Error: /Users/pbh/project/frontend/luxlab_front/platforms/android/gradlew: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':mergeDebugResources'.
> /Users/pbh/project/frontend/luxlab_front/platforms/android/res/values/strings.xml: Error: Found item String/google_app_id more than one time

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
```

`ionic run ios`

```
duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_GtalkAppData in:
    /Users/pbh/project/frontend/luxlab_front/platforms/ios/Pods/GoogleCloudMessaging/Libraries/libGcmLib.a(GtalkCore.pb.o)
    럭스랩/Plugins/cordova-plugin-firebase/FirebaseMessaging.framework/FirebaseMessaging(GtalkCore.pbobjc_4adff0f7bd059c687019835bc9c59b23.o)
ld: 42 duplicate symbols for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)


** ARCHIVE FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
    Ld /Users/pbh/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/럭스랩-frtekduffawmjpcdcfcknnsswolo/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/럭스랩/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/럭스랩.build/Debug-iphoneos/럭스랩.build/Objects-normal/arm64/럭스랩 normal arm64
(1 failure)

Error: Error code 65 for command: xcodebuild with args: -xcconfig,/Users/pbh/project/frontend/luxlab_front/platforms/ios/cordova/build-debug.xcconfig,-workspace,럭스랩.xcworkspace,-scheme,럭스랩,-configuration,Debug,-destination,generic/platform=iOS,-archivePath,럭스랩.xcarchive,archive,CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR=/Users/pbh/project/frontend/luxlab_front/platforms/ios/build/device,SHARED_PRECOMPS_DIR=/Users/pbh/project/frontend/luxlab_front/platforms/ios/build/sharedpch
```

I do not know what the problem is.

Has anyone resolved the same issue?

Is this a conflict between phonegap-plugin-push and cordova-plugin-fcm or cordovoa-plugin-firebase?

Comment: The android issue is usually resolved by updating Repistories and Google Play Services in Android Studio and checking your path variable

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue.

There was a conflict between the phonegap-plugin-push plug-in and the cordova-plugin-fcm plugin.

If I install only one of them, the above issues will be solved.